# Stacked barplot using ggplot2 - data visualisation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have very little experience with R and am trying to make a stacked barplot using ggplot2. 
I have 2 groups - control and experimental, and 2 choices - red and green. I'm not sure how to organise my data.

There were 80 animals in my trial (control n=40, experimental n=40) and they were given the choice of red and green substrate, I noted which substrate they chose, and that's the data I'm trying to plot.

I would essentially want 'Experimental' and 'Control on the x-axis, and the number of choices on the y-axis (e.g. Control, Red n=20, Control, Green = 12 etc).

Any help would be appreciated!

Edited to add:

[This is the graph it's outputting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IyOe.png)

This is the code I'm using (including suggested adjustments):

```html
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("control", "experimental"), each = 40),
                 substrate = sample (c("red","green"), 80, TRUE))

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = substrate, fill = substrate)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green"))
```

**This is the output:**

```
structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("control", "experimental"
), class = "factor"), substrate = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("green", 
"red"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-80L))
```

**output from df(behaviour) - original dataframe**

```
structure(list(group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Control", "Experimental"
), class = "factor"), substrate = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Green", 
"Red"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-80L))
```

Comment: Hi ChristyJudd, so you have tabulated your data. @AllanCameron's code assumes you haven't done that. you need to do y = <column containing counts> and geom_bar(stat="identity")

Comment: The best is if you show us how your data frame looks like :) say df is your dataframe , do dput(df) and paste the output as part of your post?

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I do dput(df) it comes up with something strange, but when I open 'df' from my global environment it shows my data? I can still paste above if you'd like. When I use the code you suggest the y-axis labels are 'red' and 'green' rather than a count of the number of red and green, which is the issue I was facing before. I can try and paste the graph above with the code I used if that would help at all?

Comment: It's ok, dput(df) gives something like structure(....) right? Paste that output (starting from structure...) as part of your post. Screen shots are not going to help much unfortunately..

Comment: I'll paste that output now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data:

```
behaviour=structure(list(group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Control", "Experimental"
), class = "factor"), substrate = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Green", 
"Red"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-80L))
```

We can tabulate your data:

```
 table(behaviour$group,behaviour$substrate)                           
               Green Red
  Control         10  30
  Experimental    27  13
```

So you can only specify fill or y with geom_bar. In your case, you specify the fill, the `geom_bar()` function will do the counting for you:

```
ggplot(behaviour,aes(x=group,fill=substrate))+
geom_bar() + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#29c7ac","#c02739"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It still doesn't seem to be counting correctly. For my control group, there is a count of green=10, red=30. For my experimental, the count should be red=13, green=27. Sorry to be such a bother!

Comment: I have no idea! I just double-checked my original data and it's definitely - cont:g=10, red=30  exp:g=27, r=13. I'm really unsure what's happening.

Comment: I'll paste the output from dput(behaviour) instead of dput(df) above (if i can format it correctly)

Comment: The figure above is correct, but I can't seem to recreate it myself.

Comment: weird? You gave the df.. what is it called in your R environment?

Comment: it's called 'behaviour' in my environment

Comment: I tried it again this morning and it seemed to work? Thank you so, so, so much for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You could have your data like this, with one row for each observation (i.e. each animal), with the group and the substrate recorded for each:

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("control", "experimental"), each = 40),
                 substrate = rep(c("green", "red", "green", "red"), c(10, 30, 27, 13)))
```

Now define your plot using `ggplot`, specifying `group` as your x axis, and `..count..` as your y axis.  Use `geom_bar` to get the stacked bars you are looking for, and finally use `scale_fill_manual` to set the colours:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = ..count.., fill = substrate)) + 
  geom_bar(colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's worked really well, except that it seems to be counting the data wrong? So, experimental ( green = 27, red = 13), and control (green = 10, red = 30), but its showing that they essentially are equal. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @ChristyJudd this was just dummy data I used for the example since I didn't have all your data. I'll update it to reflect your numbers, but it would be better to make sure that you are putting your existing data frame in to ggplot, not the dummy data I created.

Comment: My 'df' has the same data as my actual data, but isn't plotting that on the bar graph. I can't see why though. Thank you for updating your bar chart!